# C: Sorting linked list by swapping element data

Tags: c, sorting, linked-list

Given a list of moves in chess, I want to sort the list such that all capturing moves will be first in the list and non-capturing moves at the end of the list.

I'm getting an infinite loop whilst running this code and don't know why. I looked at the 4 different cases - I iterated over the list in a seemingly logical way. I would appreciate if someone more experienced could have a look. Thanks!

```
void sort(move_t* head, game_t game) {
move_t* move, *next;
int x1,y1,x2,y2;
char s;
move = head;

while(move != NULL)
{
    next = move->next;
    while(next != NULL)
    {
    if((isCapture(game,move) == 0) && (isCapture(game,next)== 1))
        {
            x1 = move->x1;
            y1 = move->y1;
            x2 = move->x2;
            y2 = move->y2;
            s = move->s;
            move->x1 = next->x1;
            move->y1 = next->y1;
            move->x2 = next->x2;
            move->y2 = next->y2;
            move->s = next->s;
            next->x1 = x1;
            next->y1 = y1;
            next->x2 = x2;
            next->y2 = y2;
            next->s = s;
            move = next;
            next = next->next;
        }
    else if((isCapture(game,move) == 1) && (isCapture(game,next)== 0))
        {
        move = move-> next;
        next = move-> next;
        }
    else if((isCapture(game,move) == 0) && (isCapture(game,next)== 0))
        {
        next = next->next;
        }
    else if((isCapture(game,move) == 1) && (isCapture(game,next)== 1))
        {
        move = move -> next;
        next = move -> next;
        }

    }
}
}
```

Comment: General advice: don't use a linked list if you need to sort the data. Use an array instead. In fact, even copying to an array, sorting the array using e.g. randomized quicksort, and then copying it back into a linked list is likely to be faster than sorting the linked list itself -- and way easier to program.

Comment: If possible, you could put capturing and non-capturing moves in separate move lists so you don't have to sort them at all.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You get an infinite loop because you only modify `move` in your inner loop. When the list is sorted, you will have all the non-winning moves at the end. Once `move` reaches the first non-winning move, the inner loop stops modifying `move` (it's your third test case, where both `isCapture` functions return 0), it only does `next = next->next`.

The outer loop will never have its condition satisfied because `move` will never reach the end of the list.